# TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined discord.js

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

***Sorry if i sound dumb saying this im new to Node.js***

I tried looking other places and couldent find an answer and the docs didnt make sense to me but im getting errors when i want my bot to send a embed that automatticly says the guilds name in it so im using `message.guild.name` and i defined message but now im getting the error =

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined

So im not sure what to do, my main code is

```
exports.run = (message) => {

const embed = new RichEmbed()
.setDescription(`Hello! Welcome to ${message.guild.name}!`)
.setColor(0xdd9323)
.setFooter(`This bot was made by Fortnitewinner21#1076 and Hextanium#5890`);

message.channel.send(embed).then(m => m.react('✅')).catch(console.error);

};
```

BTW- im v11

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined. It is saying that there is no name property in the message.guild collection, put a console.log (message.guild) before this code snippet the problem comes before this snippet.

Comment: @RafaelSalomão ok il try

Comment: Firstly nodejs uses `module.exports` not `exports`, but yea `message.guild` is undefined, this either means your command/event handler that passes in the first parameter isn't the message object or it means the code ran inside of a DMChannel, which has no guild.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a message to refer to in this case. I suggest putting this inside an event or making this into a command. But since you said you wanted it to be sent automatically you will need to use an Event or an Interval.